# How does one pronounce 'megalomaniacal?'

Tags: pronunciation

After looking up the pronunciation on various online resources such as [How to Pronounce Megalomaniacal by Emma Saying on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL655qyjeUw). I came to the conclusion that this pronunciation is mega-luh-may-knee-ak-al.

However, I then watched Head to Head — Dawkins on religion: Is Religion Good or Evil? Both people in the video [make a point about an alternative pronunciation](https://youtu.be/U0Xn60Zw03A?t=3m30s) to that which one would generally expect and that which I have determined. Mega-luh-man-eye-acal.

Does anybody have any further insights?

While we are here, what about 'controversy'? It is also used in Head to Head [here](https://youtu.be/U0Xn60Zw03A?t=2m5s). Is that correct I always thought it was "contra-versy" rather than "con-trov-ersy".

Comment: I always find the Cambridge Dictionary pretty reliable for recorded (BrE) pronunciation. I can't vouch for the AE recordings. They don't list *megalomaniacal*, but they do list [*megalomaniac*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/megalomania). Recorded pronunciation in online dictionaries can be a little hit and miss at times, especially if they are public-domain contributions, which some obviously are. Maybe we need a Pronunciation.SE?

Comment: The tonic accent in megalomaniacal is on the i.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maniacal) says *maniacal* is pronounced with *eye*. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maniacal) also says *maniacal* is pronounced with *eye*. And *maniacal* is going to have the same pronunciation as *megalomaniacal*. Your online sources (do you have more than one?) saying it's pronounced with *knee* seem rather untrustworthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED doesn't include a pronunciation for *megalomaniacal*, only for *megalomaniac*.

> ### **megalomaniac**, *adj*. and *n*.
>
> **Pronunciation:** Brit.  /ˌmɛɡ(ə)lə(ʊ)ˈmeɪnɪak/ ,  /ˌmɛɡl̩ə(ʊ)ˈmeɪnɪak/ ,
>   U.S.
>   /ˌmɛɡ(ə)loʊˈmeɪniˌæk/ ,  /ˌmɛɡ(ə)ləˈmeɪniˌæk/

(All citations are for the *OED Online*, Oxford University Press, September 2016.)

If you just tacked some sort of unaccented -al at the end, these would come close to your first suggested pronunciation. However, a clue to why the second might be preferred comes from the pronunciation guide for *maniac* and *maniacal*, respectively:

> ### **maniac**, *adj*. and *n*.
>
> Pronunciation:  Brit.   /ˈmeɪnɪak/ ,  U.S.  /ˈmeɪniˌæk/
>
> ### **maniacal**, *adj*.
>
> Pronunciation:  Brit.   /məˈnʌɪəkl/ ,  U.S.  /məˈnaɪə(k)əl/

As you can see, when going from *maniac* to *maniacal* the emphasis shifts from the first to second syllable, and the pronunciation of the vowel represented by the letter *i* changes as well, for both British and American speakers (though the exact emphasis and vowel-sound are slightly different). Using this pronunciation with the prefix *megalo-* looks like it would sound much more like the second pronunciation you reference.

FWIW, I (native speaker of American English) would use the second, "eye" pronunciation.

Comment: I'm totally baffled by the (k) in the U.S. pronunciation of *maniacal*. It can't possibly be optional, can it? Shouldn't it be /məˈnaɪək(ə)l/ instead?

Comment: @PeterShor I certainly think that *I* pronounce the k, but perhaps it represents a glottalization of some sort? Listening to the OED's audio example, the k is sort of swallowed. However, it's also possible that this is an example of the rare typo in the OED (I copied and pasted directly, and just checked again to make sure it's actually like that in the original).

Comment: The U.S. pronunciation for *diabolical* is /ˌdaɪəˈbɑlək(ə)l/, so I strongly suspect they misplaced the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

*Maniac* is pronounced /'**men**iyæk/ in [American English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) phonemics, with initial stress, but *maniacal* is pronounced /mə'**nay**əkəl/, with the stress shifted forward to the second syllable.

*Megalo-* is pronounced /'**mɛɡ**əlo/, so the whole thing sounds like two words, with two stresses: /'**mɛɡ**əlomə'**nay**əkəl/. It seems like too much word, frankly; *maniacal* is already overkill.

Answer (score 0):

*Maniac* is MAY-nee-ak, but *maniacal* is muh-NEYE-ikul.

The British mispronounce *controversy* as con-TROH-versy, when of course, the correct pronunciation is CON-traversy.

*Edit:* accepting correction from some Brits in the comments who have a lack of humor uncharacteristic of their little isle.

Comment: The British do not mispronounce controversy: they put the tonic accent on the second syllable. And there are many words where the tonic accent in BrE and AmE are different. Ain't no thang.

Comment: I don’t know what kind of English you’re talking about here, but _maniac_ certainly is not stressed on the second syllable in any kind of English that I’m familiar with. And the British in general pronounce _controversy_ with initial stress as well, just like the Americans; stressing the second syllable is a less common alternative.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I'd suggest MAY-nee-ak and con-TROH-versy. (It would be con-TRAH-ver-shal though...).

Comment: I like your edit but point out that you've spelt _humo**u**_ wrong.

Comment: If you must use re-spelling, I'd suggest writing it as "con-TROV-versy." It's the vowel in "pr**ov**idence" or "b**ovv**er boys";  "OH" looks like you're trying to indicate the vowel in "drove." The problem with "AH" was that British "short o" (the vowel in words like "lot" etc.) is not the same as British "AH" (which is found in words spelled with "ar," such as "cart").